# Bing Maps V8 Missing RouteResponseCode Enumeration?

Tags: bing-maps

We're upgrading our driving directions page from Bing Maps V7 to V8. So far so good, except for the absence of the RouteResponseCode enumeration.

Here's the V8 documentation page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt750371.aspx

The page does not show a method of gaining access to this enumeration. In V7 this attribute was made available through `Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteResponseCode`. Now it appears removed.

Can I still access this enumeration, or do I need to hardcode the values now?

Answer (score 1):

Strange. It was documented but doesn't seem to be in the SDK. Will have the team look into this to see if it was removed, or if it simply wasn't exposed publicly.